# Splitting and replacing delimited strings into new rows using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in 2 columns. The data in column B is comma delimited. I need each instance to appear on a new row while retaining it's original ID from column A. I also need the data in 3 columns so Name is in B and Number in C. It appears as so:

---

> > A--------B
> >
> > 1--------Sam Jones, 1 hours, Chris Bacon, 2 hours
> >     2--------John Jacob, 3 hours
> >     3--------John Hancock, 4 hours, Brian Smith, .5 hours

---

I am able to get it as such using my code below:

> > A--------B
> >
> > 1--------Sam Jones, 1
> >     1--------Chris Bacon, 2 hours
> >     2--------John Jacob, 3 hours
> >     3--------John Hancock, 4
> >     3--------Brian Smith, .5 hours

---

I need it to be: (notice last value in string also has hours removed when added to new line)

> > A---------B------------------------C
> >     1---------Sam Jones-----------1
> >     1---------Chris Bacon----------2
> >     2---------John Jacob-----------3
> >     3---------John Hancock-------4
> >     3---------Brian Smith----------.5

I have the following code started: (I can't manage to remove the "hours" from the last person in each delimited string and I can't get it into 3 columns)

```
Sub splitByColB()  
  Dim r As Range, i As Long, ar  
  Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").End(xlDown)  
  Do While r.Row > 1  
    ar = Split(r.Value, " hours, ")  
    If UBound(ar) >= 0 Then r.Value = ar(0)  
    For i = UBound(ar) To 1 Step -1  
      r.EntireRow.Copy  
      r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert  
      r.Offset(1).Value = ar(i)  
    Next  
    Set r = r.Offset(-1)  
  Loop  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aTemp As Variant
    Dim aResults(1 To 65000, 1 To 3) As Variant
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        aData = .Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2).Value
    End With

    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        If Len(Trim(aData(i, 2))) = 0 Then
            ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
            aResults(ResultIndex, 1) = aData(i, 1)
        Else
            aTemp = Split(aData(i, 2), ",")
            For j = LBound(aTemp) To UBound(aTemp) Step 2
                ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
                aResults(ResultIndex, 1) = aData(i, 1)
                aResults(ResultIndex, 2) = Trim(aTemp(j))
                aResults(ResultIndex, 3) = Trim(Replace(aTemp(j + 1), "hours", vbNullString, , , vbTextCompare))
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    ws.Range("A2").Resize(ResultIndex, UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

End Sub
```

Comment: It actually doesn't seem to work if column B has an initial blank value. It will skip to the next populated row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Power Query`.  It is a free MS add-in in 2010, 2013 and included in 2016 where it is called `Get & Transform`

- Split column 2 by delimiter `custom --> hours,`
- Select the ID column and `unpivot other columns`
- Select column 2 and `split by delimiter = comma`
- Remove unnecessary column
- Replace value "hours"

And if you add to the table, you can re-run the query

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Data", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Data", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("hours,", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Data.1", "Data.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Data.1", type text}, {"Data.2", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1", "Value.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Value.1", type text}, {"Value.2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns","hours","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Value.2"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use a class with the name data

```
Option Explicit

Public Id As String
Public FullName As String
Public hours As String
```

and the following code

```
Option Explicit

    Sub SplitIt()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim dataLine As data

        Set rg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Dim vDat As Variant
        vDat = rg.Columns

        Dim lDat As Variant
        Dim i As Long, j As Long

        For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
            lDat = Split(vDat(i, 2), ",")
            For j = LBound(lDat) To UBound(lDat) Step 2
                Dim hDat As Variant
                hDat = Split(Trim(lDat(j + 1)), " ")
                Set dataLine = New data
                dataLine.Id = vDat(i, 1)
                dataLine.FullName = Trim(lDat(j))
                dataLine.hours = hDat(0)
                col.Add dataLine
            Next j
        Next i

        ' Print Out
        For i = 1 To col.Count
            Set dataLine = col(i)
            rg.Cells(i, 1) = dataLine.Id
            rg.Cells(i, 2) = dataLine.FullName
            rg.Cells(i, 3) = dataLine.hours
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not split on *hours* to a) add a record delimiter and b) get rid of *hours*?

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitByColB()
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, hrs As Variant, cms As Variant
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            hrs = Split(.Cells(r, "B").Value2 & ", ", " hours, ")
            ReDim Preserve hrs(UBound(hrs) - 1)
            If CBool(UBound(hrs)) Then _
                .Cells(r, "A").Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(hrs), 1).EntireRow.Insert
            For i = UBound(hrs) To LBound(hrs) Step -1
                cms = Split(hrs(i), ", ")
                .Cells(r, "A").Offset(i, 0) = .Cells(r, "A").Value
                .Cells(r, "A").Offset(i, 1) = cms(0)
                .Cells(r, "A").Offset(i, 2) = cms(1)
            Next i
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]